How do I change my login username in Windows 9x?
A few years ago, I set up a lot of Windows 9x VMs.  During the Windows installation/setup process for several of the VMs, I, in my infinite hubris, ignored the common advice against using your actual name as your username. In the intervening years, my egg cracked, and now I have several VMs deadnaming me.
Normally, the solution to this sort of problem would be to change my username on those systems (as I've indeed done with a number of VMs installed with various Windows NT versions all the way back to NT 3.1), but, out of all three major Windows 9x versions, none appear to have any obvious way of doing this.  (I don't know if enabling multi-user settings on 98 and ME would make this easier, and Windows 95 doesn't even have that option.)
I would like to remove my deadname from these VMs and replace it with something else, without wiping the VMs and reinstalling them with their respective Windows versions.  How can I accomplish this?  (For Windows 98 and ME, would enabling multi-user settings help with this?)

Is it enough to rename the Windows\username.pwl file and Windows\Profiles\username directory? I remember that doing something on Windows 98 SE, but I don't remember whether the result was success or failure.

I think this can be folded into Managing and deleting users in Windows 95 prior to Internet Explorer 4 – even though the other question does not mention renaming explicitly.

But back to the real issue – I discovered that after renaming the files there’s one other thing to do: in SYSTEM.INI, there is a [Password Lists] section that maps user names to PWL files. I assume it will have to be edited as well.

Discussion about trans jargon has been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@user3840170 If that's all there is to it, could you write up an answer? Either to this question (my preference) or to the other one (if you think they're duplicates). To my knowledge, that information's new to the site.

@user3840170: I'd say this one's just about different enough from that other question to stand on its own, given that renaming things that already exist is often quite a different (and more difficult) matter in computing than deleting them and making a new one, although in this particular case it turned out to not be that hard.

On every computer OS I've used at home since the mid-1990s, that needed a username, I've chosen 'Mike'. Why shouldn't I do that? My government department account username was harvey.

@MichaelHarvey: "Why shouldn't I do that?"  Because personal names can change, and many computer systems have difficulty with changing usernames.

I've been Mike or Michael since 1952, so I personally won't have that problem, and I've had sysadmin roles since 1983.

Windows 95 user management is very basic. Users can be created at login time with no checks in the default setup: so when your VM starts, replace your old login with the new one and enter your new password. You’ll be asked for confirmation of the new password, and that’s it, your new user is available for use. If you enter a blank password, Windows will log you in automatically.
You can then delete the old information following the steps in the linked answer. If you’ve only done basic Windows 95 setup there won’t even be a “Profiles” directory to clean up, just the PWL file.
On later versions of Windows 9x (Windows 95 with Internet Explorer 4, Windows 98, and Windows Me), the same technique can be used to create a new user, but you might as well use the “Users” Control Panel applet:

The first time you use this, if multiple profile support hasn’t been enabled yet, it will prompt you to set it up.
Once profiles are supported, you’ll see the list of users. Select your current user, and click “Make a Copy” with your new login name. You will then be able to log out (from the Start menu), log in with the new user, and delete the old one.
If you also want to update the “registered owner”, you can do so by modifying the value associated with the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOwner key in the registry.

From what I recall, Windows 9x makes no use of your identity at all - it is just passed on to network software (like a lanman file server) that might care.

@dave it can use it to choose “profiles” (so each user gets their own set of documents etc.; with IE, bookmarks and so on). But there is no protection between users.

It's possible you might run into problems with the Briefcase, on the off chance you were using it. I think that's one of the few (only?) things in Win95 that relies on the username for anything that's not network related.
